# How to determine the values of $x$ for which $f(x)=x^4-8x^3+22x^2-24x+21$ is increasing and for which it is decreasing.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Determine the values of $x$ for which $f(x)=x^4-8x^3+22x^2-24x+21$ is increasing and for which it is decreasing.

- How do you solve $f(x)$ here?
- How can you get the values of $x$?
- How do you solve when a function is increasing & decreasing?

Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Edit: This is my attempt

> $f(x)=x^4-8x^3+22x^2-24x+21$
>
> $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\begin{pmatrix}x^4-8x^3+22x^2-24x+21\end{pmatrix}$
>
> $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}x^4-8\frac{d}{dx}x^3+22\frac{d}{dx}x^2-24\frac{d}{dx}x+21\frac{d}{dx}0$
>
> $f'(x)=4x^3-24x^2+44x-24$
>
> $f'(x)=4\begin{pmatrix}x^3-6x^2+11x-6\end{pmatrix}$
>
> $f'(x)=x\begin{pmatrix}x^2+11\end{pmatrix}-6\begin{pmatrix}x^2+1\end{pmatrix}$ And this is where I'm stuck at. Assuming I did everything correctly.

Comment: Look at the derivative

Answer (score 1):

Since $f^\prime=4(x^3-6x^2+11x-6)=4(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, $f$ is increasing (decreasing) when $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ is positive (negative). Note that $x>3\implies f^\prime>0$, and $f^\prime$ changes sign at each of $1$, $2$, $3$. So $f$ is increasing for $1<x<2$ and for $x>3$.

Note: if you're wondering how I factorized $f^\prime$, the honest answer is I've seen that monic cubic before in certain combinatorial contexts, but the helpful answer is the rational root theorem implies its only possible rational roots are factors of the constant term $-6$, so it makes sense to evaluate it at $\pm1,\,\pm2,\,\pm3$. Once you find a root, you can take out a linear factor, leaving a quadratic factor, which is easier to handle. No need to break out [Cardano's formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula).

Comment: I edited to show my attempt. And I'm really confused now.

Comment: @RomyJose Try factorizing the way I recommended. Can you see that $f^\prime(1)=0$? That means $x-1$ is a factor. But then $f^\prime=4(x-1)(x^2+ax+6)$, where the $x^2$ coefficient determines $a$. See if you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Differentiate $f(x).$ Then it is increasing whenever $f'(x)>0$ and decreasing whenever $f'(x)<0.$